# Create Form Data using php array for CURL Form data

Tags: javascript, php, curl

i have some request using ajax that i want to call it using curl. 
that ajax form data should be like this

```
q:user_id(367091) {
  followed_by.after(10) {
    count,
    page_info {
      end_cursor,
      has_next_page
    },
    nodes {
      id,
      is_verified,
      followed_by_viewer,
      requested_by_viewer,
      full_name,
      profile_pic_url,
      username
    }
  }
}
```

i have try to write it and there is my code

```
$array_post= 
array(
    "q" => array(
        "" => "",
    ),
);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_post);
```

i have a lil bit confused to fill like user_id,followed_by.after that can this write with nested array ?? 
how to make class / object variable / something like pointer might be, so we have array of data and own value. someone help please

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. What do you mean by "How to make class / object like pointer" and "have array of data and own value". Isn't value a data?

Comment: sorry for my bad in english. can u guys just translate it into array in php ? i mean, user_id is array right ? user_id value = 367091 and it have array element array is followed_by.after ? and, followed_by.after have value = 10 and have element like count, arr page_info, arr nodes. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: forgot to mention @DawidFerenczy

Comment: That form data listing is an output of what?

Comment: xhr that i take using inspect element. @DawidFerenczy

Comment: What do you mean by the "inspect element"? Are you checking it using a browser's developer tools?

Comment: correct @DawidFerenczy dont worry man i solved that problem, now its fixed. thanks for your help

Comment: Great, I'm glad you have solved it. You should provide a correct answer (better) or delete your question completely (worse) in that case. Definitely don't leave it as it is, please.

Comment: Ok i post the correct answer @DawidFerenczy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be like this.

```
$array_post= 
array(
    "q" => "user_id(367091) {
  followed_by.after(10) {
    count,
    page_info {
      end_cursor,
      has_next_page
    },
    nodes {
      id,
      is_verified,
      followed_by_viewer,
      requested_by_viewer,
      full_name,
      profile_pic_url,
      username
    }
  }
}",
);
$field_string = urldecode(http_build_query($array_post));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
```

Comment: Thanks. But wait, you needed just a hard-coded string, not any structure, right? So what have you been asking about actually? You just copy&pasted your sample request as is.

Comment: actually i didnt know if it can be only as string, i just trial, error, googling and it works man. i was think that curl should be in structure of array, but it should be work in a way like that. what i have been asking is the way to copy xhr in browser developer input post data, so my web service can do it something like that @DawidFerenczy

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$test = array(
    'q:user_id(367091)' => array(
        'followed_by.after(10)' => array(
            'count' => '',
            'page_info' => array(
                'end_cursor' => '',
                'has_next_page' => ''
            ),
            'nodes' => array(
                'id' => '',
                'is_verified' => '',
                'followed_by_viewer' => '',
                'requested_by_viewer' => '',
                'full_name' => '',
                'profile_pic_url' => '',
                'username' => ''
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This output looks similar to what you need:

```
print_r(json_encode($test, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Comment: i got error string(48) "{"status":"fail","message":"invalid parameters"}"

Comment: OK, in that case, try to think about that. What about checking how does parameters look using the same method as you did before and posting what's different?